# Blank screen with blinking cursor 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I am new to Linux. I have a spare, old Sony Vaio laptop and installed the Ubuntu Desktop 20.04. Installation went well but I got a blank screen and a blinking cursor on the left corner of the monitor.  I tried the Cntl+Alt+F3 but nothing happens. Please help.

Update: I got it working now. The problem was on my keyboard. Using external keyboard worked this time. Thank you.

Comment: Was there a specific reason to install 20.04 instead of the newer Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS?